# Visual Studio Project Linker: is it possible to populate destination project automatically?

Tags: silverlight, visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7

I have a Silverlight project with lots of source files. Now I want to create a new WP7 project using the same source code files (but obviously, target WP7).

I link the WP7 project to the existing Silverlight project using Project Linker. However, this does not automatically generate links to the existing files in the source project.

Is there any way using Project Linker to automatically populate the destination project with the already existing files in the source project? Or do I manually have to add links in the WP7 project to all previously existing files in the source project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the same problem, but I resolved it.
Simply exclude all files from "source" project and then re-include them.
In this way project linker refresh its references adding all links!
It worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what you but I think you'll have to do manually in VS.Net, but if all the files in the same directory you can add all the files in one go, it sounds as though you want to select the 'Add as Link' option once the add 'Existing items' dialog is displayed.

Comment: Thanks AwkwardCoder for your answer. So far I have used the 'Add As Link' option and added the files manually when creating the new project. 
However, there are also several sub-folders in the source project, and I would like to avoid the hassle of re-creating and filling these folders manually in the destination project.
But maybe this is too much to ask of the Project Linker? Perhaps it is more of a task for a "New project from existing" template?